# Spring shell colorized output

Tags: java, spring-shell

I want to colorize my console output in spring-shell. 
Something like:

```
System.out.println("\red; red text");
```

I know about colorized JUL logging output, but it's not enought.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Ansi values in your output.

Here is my class with some color constants:

```
public class AnsiConstants {
  public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
  public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
  public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
  public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
  public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
  public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
  public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
  public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
  public static final String ANSI_GRAY = "\u001B[37m";
  public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37;1m"; 
}
```

Your example can be generated with:

```
System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "red text" + ANSI_RESET);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are based on Spring Boot using [AnsiOutput](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ansi/AnsiOutput.html) with [AnsiColor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ansi/AnsiColor.html) should work. Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationReady(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    System.out.println(AnsiOutput.toString(
        AnsiColor.GREEN, "Service started successfully", AnsiColor.DEFAULT));
  }

  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationFailed(ApplicationFailedEvent event) {
    System.err.println(AnsiOutput.toString(
        AnsiColor.RED, "Service startup failed", AnsiColor.DEFAULT));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```